# problems using wireshark capture local files opened in browser

Tags: protocols, wireshark, pcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I have a xml doc saved locally, I want to generate a pcap file from the xml doc. I tried doing this by opening wireshark, tailor the capture for the Ethernet interface and then start capturing, I then open the document in my web browser. This doesn't seem to be working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the xml doc with a `file:///foo.xml` url?

Comment: Yes I am in chrome file:///C:/Users/foo.xml

Comment: That doesn't need to use the network.  Now, if you specified a file on another host, or you accessed the xml doc through a web server running locally using `http:`, that would be different.  Note that the network capture using `file:` to a remote host would be a fairly messy capture of the SMB protocol.